# Fullcalendar ending a starting time 10 minutes after the hour I actually selected

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I'm developing a booking platform with fullcalendar, right now when I send the start and end times to the PHP (it's actually laravel) file that saves the info the database, the time is 10 minutes after the hour I actually selected, so for example if I select 10:00 to 12:00 fullcalendar sends 10:10 to 12:10,  I'm not sure if its a matter of formatting or what, I've been looking around in forums but I've got nothing, help!! Thanks!

This is how I formatted the time:

```
save_start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start , "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
save_end   = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
```

These are my calendar settings:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaDay'
        },
        validRange: function(nowDate) {
            return {
                start: nowDate,
                end: nowDate.clone().add(2, 'months')
            };
        },
        hiddenDays: [ 2, 4 ],
        allDaySlot: false,
        lang:'es',
        slotEventOverlap:false,
        slotDuration: '00:60:00',
        slotMinutes: 60,
        timezone: 'America/Mexico_City',
        minTime: schedule_start+ ":00:00",
        maxTime: schedule_end+ ":00:00",
        defaultDate: '2017-09-12',
        slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
        contentHeight: window_height,
        navLinks: true, 
        editable: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectOverlap:false,
        eventDurationEditable:true,
        selectConstraint:{
            start: schedule_start+':00', 
            end: schedule_end+':00',
            dow: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
        },
        select: function(start, end, allDay,view) {

            save_start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start , "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
            save_end   = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");


        },
        events: reservations,
        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

            // Agregamos el botón para eliminar la reservación
            if (view.name== 'agendaDay' && event.className =='new-reservation') {
                element.find(".fc-content").prepend('<span class="closeon"><i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');
            }
            // Eliminamos la reservación del calendario delete
            element.find(".closeon").on('click', function() {
                delete_reservation(event.id,event.title);

            });
        },  
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay', date);  

        },
        eventClick:function (calEvent, jsEvent, view){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', "agendaDay",calEvent.start);
        }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with 10 minutes extra, it's a simple error in your format string.

fullCalendar uses momentJS underneath to format dates. The tokens you can use for outputting in certain formats are given here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

You're using `MM` which represents months. Since the current month is October, that's probably why you're seeing 10. Last month you'd have seen 09. You need to use `mm` instead to represent minutes. You have a similar problem with seconds - technically you're outputting fractional seconds, although the level of detail of the selection means you probably don't notice.

This:

```
save_start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start , "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
save_end   = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

will give you the correct result.